# Is an answer a post? is a comment?

Tags: support, posts

What is a "Post" defined as? Does it include all of the following, or just a subset:

- Questions
- Answers
- Comments
- Community Wiki Questions
- Community Wiki Answers
- Chat message
- other things?

I'm asking in the context of Badge definitions like "Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months".

Comment: As a rough guideline, if you can't (at any level of privilege) edit other people's content (comments, chat messages, etc.), it won't count towards any editing-related badges.

Comment: Thanks Anna, I agree this is a duplicate of that other question. However, that one is certainly not easy to search for when wondering 'what is a post'. It's not even tagged 'posts'.

Comment: That makes sense. The use of it both as a noun `'Edited 100 posts'` and a verb `'Posted 10 messages in chat'` made the definition of it more ambiguous than needed, on the Badges page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Post as far as I can tell from own experience in Stack Exchange refers to either a Question or an Answer, nothing more and nothing less.

Being CW is not relevant, it's still a post.

Comment is *not* a post.

Other things? Well, there are blog posts but they are not a direct part of the Q&A sites.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of `Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months`, "post" only encompasses two things:

1. Questions
2. Answers

The rest, while they're still site content, are not considered "posts".