# Why is an answer only an "answer" if it was deleted from review?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, 10k-tools, post-notices

With the new post notices showing above posts, I am noticing an interesting discrepancy. As a user with 10,000 reputation on some sites I can see deleted answers, and they now are accompanied by a notice that says that they are hidden, and who deleted them.

When an answer was deleted regularly by users with delete privileges the notice says:

> This post is hidden.

[image: Screenshot of quoted text]

When an answer was deleted from review the notice says:

> This answer is hidden.

[image: Screenshot of quoted text]

As far as I'm aware (and see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231572/390967)) the term "answer" includes all answers, while the term "post" includes all answers *and* all questions. I don't think that the process of how an answer was deleted relates to that.

Why is an answer deleted regularly called a "post", while an answer deleted from review is called an "answer"?

Was this differentiation done deliberately? If so, to what end?

Answer (score 5):

> All notices are now internally consistent with use of post/answer (some of the notices are reused for questions and answers - thus the usage of "post") – Yaakov Ellis♦ Nov 6 at 8:19
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337087/281934